# Error 500 Populating Select From MSSQL

Tags: php, html, select, joomla

I am attempting to connect my php to a SQL server database but each time I try to load the page, I get a 500 error.

This is the syntax I am using, and while the below is garbage data, I am actually passing in valid username and password in my production file

```
<?php
$db_host = '.\SQLEXPRESS';
$db_user = 'sa';  
$db_pwd = 'pass@word1';
$database = 'test';
$table = 'testIDtable';

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);
if( !$conn )
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql = "SELECT Top 1 saleID FROM {$table}";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if (!$result) {
 die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option vale=\"{$row['saleID']}\">{$row['saleID']}</option>";
}
?>
```

Edit....->->->->->

This is full page syntax, is there a syntax issue that I have?  The page will load as it should until I add in this block

```
$db_host = 'Host';
$db_user = 'User';  
$db_pwd = 'PWD';
$database = 'DB';

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);
if( !$conn )
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql = "Select Top 1 saleID From testIDtable";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if (!$result) {
 die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option vale=\"{$row['saleID']}\">{$row['saleID']}</option>";
}
```

Now this is the full syntax of my page..

```
{source}

 <form method="POST">

<html>
<tbody>  

Start Date:<input type="date" name="startdate" value="<?=$_POST['startdate']?>">

 End Date:<input type="date" name="enddate" value="<?=$_POST['enddate']?>">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Info">

</tbody>

</html>

 </form>

<?php  
$db_host = 'Host';
$db_user = 'User';  
$db_pwd = 'PWD';
$database = 'DB';

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);
if( !$conn )
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql = "Select Top 1 saleID From testIDtable";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if (!$result) {
 die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option vale=\"{$row['saleID']}\">{$row['saleID']}</option>";
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$option = array();

$option['driver'] = 'mssql'; 
$option['host'] = 'Host'; 
$option['user'] = 'User'; 
$option['password'] = 'PWD'; 
$option['database'] = 'DB'; 
$option['prefix'] = '';

$db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "Query 2 to populate a table"; 

$db->setQuery($query); 
$query = $db->loadObjectList();

?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
//Building out headers here
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach( $query as $res ) { 
print "<tr>";
//Writing results from query here
print "</tr>";
}

}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
{/source}
```

Second Edit to Post ....->->->->-> 

I altered the problem MSSQL connection string to the below and the page loads as it should now (no more 500 error) however, the Select is not created?

```
$option = array();

$option['driver'] = 'mssql'; 
$option['host'] = 'Host Name'; 
$option['user'] = 'user'; 
$option['password'] = 'password'; 
$option['database'] = 'Database'; 
$option['prefix'] = '';

$db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "Select Top 1 saleID From testIDtable";

$db->setQuery($query); 
$query = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach( $query as $res ) {
    echo "<option vale=\"{$row['saleID']}\">{$row['saleID']}</option>";
}
```

Comment: it's a server error; check your logs

Comment: @Fred-ii- -> I do not have access to the server logs :(

Comment: use php's error reporting then and set to catch and display, as well as error checking on the query

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` is a mysqli_ function and not `sqlsrv_` btw. Those don't intermix. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

Comment: query is sound - I verified it in SSMS before moving over to php.  I will look up using php error reporting.  Very new to this!

Comment: I changed `fetch_assoc()` to `($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))` and now I still get a 500 Error

Comment: Try out the first example from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php and replace what you need in there to match your db/table/rows and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and error checking on the query http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php - There isn't much else I can add to this.

Comment: I will look through the tuts that you linked to, I also edited my post to show full page syntax and the block of code that is causing the error 500 to be displayed.  Not sure if that will help any further or not.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: `<form method="POST">` and `</form>` should go inside `<body></body>` not inside `<html></html>` - your html markup is invalid. That may or may not fix this (to a certain extent). If you view your html source, you should also see a few `undefined index` notices/warnings; that's what I said about error reporting earlier.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - this presents this error on my page - Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Comment: Well now you know what the error is! Did you activate the php sql server extension? Did you load the SQLServer client software? Getting access to SQLServer can be a bit of a pain and its not activated by default normally

Comment: @RiggsFolly -  hmmm not sure.  How would I check those two things?  I did not install the Joomla, just attempting to use it :)  ---- Using the `$option = array();` syntax from my second connection works perfectly, could the "trouble" code block be converted to use the same connection?

Comment: What OS are you using? Basically is you are not sure I am guess the answer is no

Comment: @RiggsFolly - not sure what OS the Joomla install was performed on (windows/linux - if I had to guess I would say it's a linux install running lamp) but the PC I am attempting to run this PHP on is Windows 10

Comment: So you are trying to get to a remote server, right? Oh and I would have to assume SQLServer would be installed on a Windows OS as its a Windows database

Comment: @RiggsFolly - the Joomla install is on a MySQL install, I am wanting to query a separate SQLServer install

Comment: Take a look at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: @RiggsFolly - and I would need to install this on my local machine or on the server that is hosting Joomla?

Comment: The local machine

Comment: Step 3 of install instructions  - 3. When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory --- how do I know my Php extension directory?